# Input::file() returns nothing

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

I am simply trying to upload an image using laravel frame work but I am facing difficulty. My problem is `$file=Input::file();` returns nothing and after this when I write `$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();` then I get this error:

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

Here is my Html code

```
<form action="enter-input" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input    name='image' style="width:194px;"type='file' class='form-control'>
<input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my controller code

```
$file= Input::file('image');    
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

The first line returns nothing and the second line shows this error `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object`. I am new to Laravel.

Comment: Please try to include the `laravel-4` **or** `laravel-5` tag in your question. There *usually* isn't much difference between the two, but it's still better to let us know which version you're using so we can provide more focused answers.

Comment: i am using laravel 5

Comment: Ok. I added the tag for `laravel-5` to the question for you, but you can always edit it yourself if you need to.

Comment: ok thanks :) what should i do now is there any alternative or any possible solution for this problem?

Comment: I haven't done file uploading via Laravel, but it seems like you have some good answers, hopefully they will be able to help you further.

Comment: @TimLewis after facing such problems in basic little tasks in laravel i am thinking to stick with codeigniter ;)

Comment: Haha never worked with that, but they all do the same thing, just in different ways. I can't stand other frameworks like Zend or CakePhp, but whatever works best for you.

Comment: Your action is wrong, `enter-input` doesn't seem a valid url also your method should be POST instead of GET

Answer (score 1):

method may be post..

You can try blade template for your form

```
{{Form::open(['url'=>'/enter-input','method'=>'POST','files'=>true])}}
//
{{Form::close()}}
```

you can check if the file was uploaded by,

```
if (Input::hasFile('image')){
    //
}
```

if you are in laravel 5 then you need to import `Input` class in top of the controller.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class YourController extends Controller {
```

Thank you.

Comment: how can i import input file please tell me how to do it?

Comment: even `if (Input::hasFile('image')){
    //
}` dosen't become true

Answer (score 1):

Change `method="get"` to `method="post"`.

Comment: used post the name of the image is showing in url above but still the same problem exists

Comment: Did you enable file upload in your php.ini? There should be `file_uploads = On`

Comment: in which folder it is normally located please tell me the path?

Comment: You can use `php_ini_loaded_file()` to get path of `php.ini` which your script is currently using.

Comment: Before `$file = Input::file('image');` put `dd($_FILES);` (as someone below suggested).

Comment: `array(1) { ["image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "anum.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php2490.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(43944) } }` it shows this

Comment: Ok. So the file is sent. Can you please post your routes and filters files too?

Answer (score 1):

On top of your code do a var_dump($_FILES) so that you are sure the file gets sent by the form. Please paste here your var_dump. Also add a space between type and the previous attribute in your form.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, after an hours struggling I've found that the files I uploading is too big than it allowed.

solved it by increasing `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini` file.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```